# input height differences in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

Why height in Chrome is bigger than Firefox of input

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/89Msh/1/

```
select, input, textarea, button {
    font: 99% sans-serif;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

body, select, input, textarea {
    color: #444444;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
}


input, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;

    line-height: 1.5;
}


input {
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-right: 29px;
    padding: 3px 3px 0;
    width: 206px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: try reseting the css property of input, i mean reset margin, padding to 0. try this, i am not sure

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem is essentially `line-height`.

Chrome sees `line-height` much like it sees `height` and Firefox doesn't.

Adding height to the input should solve the problem, though you should be careful that your `line-height` and `height` match.

For example: `height: 20px; line-height: 20px;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/e2agj/1/ - Last example input is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I added height along with line-height. it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `padding` instead of height to push the total height of the input. Doing so, I do not have to fight around with the different interpretations of Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try overflow:hidden on input

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the way you styled the `font` for the `input`.

```
select, input, textarea, button {
    font: 99% sans-serif;
}
```

Each browser has its own rendering for `sans-serif`, as that is really not a font.

Therefore, without a specific font set, you could expect some inconsistencies.

Comment: I think it's not because size is same here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/4wfvD/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Chrome & Firefox on select elements:

```
height: 20px;
padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had to combine `line-height` AND `padding` to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

I had gone throught same input line-height problem across **Firefox** , **Chrome** & **Opera** browsers. So I combined line-height , height and font-size for the appropriate look.

```
input {                   
        line-height: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: 45px;
      }
```