# How to vertically align an image inside a div

Tags: css, image, vertical-alignment

How can you align an image inside of a containing `div`?

### Example

In my example, I need to vertically center the `<img>` in the `<div>` with `class ="frame`":

```
<div class="frame" style="height: 25px;">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
</div>
```

`.frame`'s height is fixed and the image's height is unknown. I can add new elements in `.frame` if that's the only solution. I'm trying to do this on Internet  Explorer 7  and later, WebKit, Gecko.

See the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4RPFa/61/).

```css
.frame {
    height: 25px;      /* Equals maximum image height */
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;

    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class=frame>
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=250 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=25 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=23 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=21 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
   <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=19 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=17 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=15 />
 </div>
<div class=frame>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=13 />
 </div>
<div class=frame>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=11 />
 </div>
<div class=frame>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=9 />
 </div>
<div class=frame>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=7 />
 </div>
<div class=frame>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=5 />
 </div>
<div class=frame>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=3 />
 </div>
```

Comment: Hello, sorry but I disagree about use a helper here being the most valuated solution. But It is not the only way. Others are same supported by browsers. I offer a solution here down stackoverflow.com/a/43308414/7733724 and W3C.org about info. You could check. Cheers

Comment: Reading Centring Things article on W3C  will be useful: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Perfect guide for align https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: I think the key is line-height in .frame to make this work

Answer (score 2317, accepted):

The only (and the best cross-browser) way as I know is to use an `inline-block` helper with `height: 100%` and `vertical-align: middle` on both elements.

So there is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/4570/

```css
.frame {
    height: 25px;      /* Equals maximum image height */
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap; /* This is required unless you put the helper span closely near the img */

    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=250px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=25px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=23px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=21px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=19px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=17px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=15px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=13px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=11px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=9px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=7px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=5px />
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=3px />
</div>
```

Or, if you don't want to have an extra element in modern browsers and don't mind using Internet Explorer expressions, you can use a pseudo-element and add it to Internet Explorer using a convenient Expression, that runs only once per element, so there won't be any performance issues:

The solution with `:before` and `expression()` for Internet Explorer: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/4571/

```css
.frame {
    height: 25px;      /* Equals maximum image height */
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;

    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.frame:before,
.frame_before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 160px;
}

/* Move this to conditional comments */
.frame {
    list-style:none;
    behavior: expression(
        function(t){
            t.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<span class="frame_before"></span>');
            t.runtimeStyle.behavior = 'none';
        }(this)
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=250px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=25px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=23px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=21px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=19px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=17px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=15px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=13px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=11px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=9px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=7px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=5px /></div>
<div class="frame"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=3px /></div>
```

---

How it works:

1. When you have two `inline-block` elements near each other, you can align each to other's side, so with `vertical-align: middle` you'll get something like this:

   [image: Two aligned blocks]
2. When you have a block with fixed height (in `px`, `em` or another absolute unit), you can set the height of inner blocks in `%`.
3. So, adding one `inline-block` with `height: 100%` in a block with fixed height would align another `inline-block` element in it (`<img/>` in your case) vertically near it.

Comment: PAY ATTENTION that the: `<img src=""/>` is NOT inside of the `<span></span>` helper that was added. It is outside. I just about pulled every strand of my hair our by not realizing this.

Comment: It seems like you also need to add "white-space: nowrap;" to the frame or you will run into an issue if you have line break between your image and the helper span. It took me an hour why this solution wasn't working for me.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. I've applied the same methodology to an `img` without a `.helper` and it works fine. Just make the `img` and `inline-block` and it can vertically align properly.

Comment: Pay attention this only works when the img is less height than the frame. if the img is higher than frame, its not aligned to middle.

Answer (score 582):

This might be useful:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.image {
    min-height: 50px
}
```

Comment: If you wish to also horizontally align the image, add left:0; right: 0; to img

Comment: If you don't know the size of the image in advance then make a duplicate image:

`.img1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.img2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}`

Answer (score 571):

**matejkramny's solution is a good start, but oversized images have a wrong ratio.**

Here's my fork:

Demo: https://jsbin.com/lidebapomi/edit?html,css,output

[image: preview]

---

HTML:

```
<div class="frame">
  <img src="foo"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.frame {
    height: 160px; /* Can be anything */
    width: 160px; /* Can be anything */
    position: relative;
}
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 428):

A three-line solution:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

This applies to anything.

From [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

Comment: If this solution is crossbrowser it should deinitely be on the top!

Comment: Works incorrectly for iphones (ios) if image is inside <a>. Fixed it in this way:

```
a.with-centered-image {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This and not the above solutions worked for me. Others solutions tend to make a fixed height, or stretch the image to adjust to 100% of the container. This option respects the proportions while keeping this on place.

Comment: This solutions also leaves out the need for a 'helper'. Shorter code is better. It also works fine if you want to have the image smaller than the div, e.g. 80%.

Comment: it also works with position: absolute;
with additional right: 5px it is possible to place on right side

Comment: 2023-09-27, works for me. Add `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)` to make it horizontal and vertical center aligned.

Answer (score 157):

A *pure* CSS solution:

```css
.frame {
  margin: 1em 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-height: 25px;
  max-width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #3A6F9A;
}
```

```html
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=250 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=25 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=23 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=21 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=19 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=17 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=15 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=13 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=11 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=9 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=7 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=5 />
</div>
<div class=frame>
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=3 />
</div>
```

Key stuff

```
// position: relative; - in .frame holds the absolute element within the frame
// top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; - this is key for centering a component
// margin: auto; - centers the image horizontally & vertically
```

Answer (score 149):

For a more modern solution, and if there is no need to support legacy browsers, you can do this:

```css
.frame {
    display: flex;
    /**
    Uncomment 'justify-content' below to center horizontally.
    ✪ Read below for a better way to center vertically and horizontally.
    **/

    /* justify-content: center; */
    align-items: center;
}

img {
    height: auto;

    /**
    ✪ To center this image both vertically and horizontally,
    in the .frame rule above comment the 'justify-content'
    and 'align-items' declarations,
    then uncomment 'margin: auto;' below.
    **/

    /* margin: auto; */
}

/* Styling stuff not needed for demo */
.frame {
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #222;
}
p {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}
img {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9988/hand-pointing.png">
</div>
```

Here's a Pen using Flexbox: http://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/aa0ee8e6021087b6e2460664a0fa3f3e

**EDIT 1/13/22**

There's a better way to do this using CSS Grid and the `place-content` shorthand:

```css
.frame-text-grid {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    /**
    ✪ "place-content" is the shorthand for "align-content" and "justify-content".    
    ✪ The "place-content" shorthand requires two values, the first one is for "align-content" and the second one for "justify-content". If only one value is present (like in this demo), then that single value is applied to both directions.    
    ✪ Comment the "place-content: center;" declaration above to see how the elements are spread along the height of the container.
    **/
}
```

```html
<div class="ctnr frame-text-grid">
    <h2>Using Grid and <code>place-content</code></h2>
    <p>Only two lines are needed to center vertically and horizontally.</p>
</div>
```

Here's a Pen using CSS Grid: https://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/c4e27f1e74542618d73e21f7c2276272?editors=0100

Comment: This "grid" solution is easy, thanks for updating us. It also helps with long, horizontal images combined with `overflow:hidden` and `max-width` to reduce the distortion of weird aspect ratios. In other words, you might want to crop the sides of a long image, in addition to solving the main problem with vertical images.

Answer (score 102):

This way you can center an image vertically ([demo](http://jsbin.com/iBasEkAs/3/)):

```
div{
  height: 150px; // Internet Explorer 7 fix
  line-height: 150px;
}
img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 54):

Also, you can use Flexbox to achieve the correct result:

```css
.parent {
  align-items: center; /* For vertical align */
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 250px;
  /* justify-content: center; <- for horizontal align */
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-icons-circular-black/512/stackoverflow-128.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 45):

There is a **super easy** solution with **flexbox!**

```
.frame {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Yes but you can hardly see it in all of the answers. I was trying to highlight it simply and clearly as it's a much much easier solution than all of the other answers.

Comment: This is the best answer that also worked for me. But in my case in the frame "inline-flex" worked better for me. and for the image inside it i added: "vertical-align: middle".

Comment: Flexbox has a really wide range support nowadays. This is the easiest solution (and probably your responsive will thank you). 
support documentation: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 24):

Imagine you have

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

And css:

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
}
.wrap img {
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

### CSS Grid

If you want to align a single image vertically inside an image container you can use this:

```
.img-container {
  display: grid;
}

img { 
  align-self: center;
}
```

```css
.img-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column; 
  background: #BADA55;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
}

img.vertical-align {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
  <img class="vertical-align" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
</div>
```

If you want to align multiple images inside an image container you can use this:

```
.img-container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.img-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #BADA55;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
</div>
```

Please note that I have used `grid-auto-flow: column` in both the cases because otherwise the elements wrap to a row with specifying explicit grid items. In the question code, I see the item centered horizontally too. In that case, just make use of the `place-items: center` instead of `align-items: center`.

Answer (score 22):

You could try setting the CSS of PI to `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 21):

You can try the below code:

```css
.frame{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame" style="height: 25px;">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

**Background image solution**

I removed the image element altogether and set it as background of the div with a class of `.frame`

http://jsfiddle.net/URVKa/2/

This at least works fine on Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 6 and Chrome  13.

I checked, and this solution will not work to shrink images larger than 25 pixels height. There is a property called `background-size` which does set the size of the element, but it is CSS 3 which would conflict with Internet Explorer 7 requirements.

I would advice you to either redo your browser priorities and design for the best available browsers, or get some server-side code to resize the images if you'd want to use this solution.

Answer (score 12):

This works for modern browsers (2016 at time of edit) as shown in this [demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/JRaQbP)

```
.frame {
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #83A7D3;          
}
.frame img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It is very important that you either give the images a class or use inheritance to target the images that you need centered. In this example we used `.frame img {}` so that only images wrapped by a div with a class of `.frame` would be targeted.

Comment: only ie7, just put line-height:25px;

Comment: it doesn't seem to be properly aligned even on firefox and chrome ( http://jsfiddle.net/4RPFa/19/ )

Comment: works perfectly.

Answer (score 12):

http://jsfiddle.net/MBs64/

```
.frame {
    height: 35px;      /* Equals maximum image height */
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    display: block;
    max-height: 35px;
    max-width: 160px;
}
```

The key property is `display: table-cell;` for `.frame`. `Div.frame` is displayed as inline with this, so you need to wrap it in a block element.

This works in Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer 8 (and later).

UPDATE

For Internet Explorer 7 we need to add a CSS  expression:

```
*:first-child+html img {
    position: relative;
    top: expression((this.parentNode.clientHeight-this.clientHeight)/2+"px");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You could do this:

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/DZ8vW/1

### CSS

```
.frame {
    height: 25px;      /* Equals maximum image height */
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 1em 0;
    position: relative; /* Changes here... */
}
img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 160px;
    top: 50%;           /* Here.. */
    left: 50%;          /* Here... */
    position: absolute; /* And here */
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$("img").each(function(){
    this.style.marginTop = $(this).height() / -2 + "px";
})
```

Comment: Nice. Any chance for a pure-css solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no unless you want to use tables or drop compatibility with older versions of IE. :( If you knew the exact size of the images before hand it would be different, but not without that it's not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: @Joseph How would you fix it with tables?

Comment: @Benjamin Udink ten Cate It's messy but it could be done this way: http://jsfiddle.net/DZ8vW/2/ (this is not advised, but should work)

Comment: Well it suits arnauds needs perfectly. No JS, only CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 8):

### Solution using a table and table cells

Sometimes it should be solved by displaying as table/table-cell. For example, a fast title screen. It is a recommended way by W3 also. I recommend you check this link called *[Centering a block or image](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#block)* from W3C.org.

The tips used here are:

- Absolute positioning container displayed as table
- Vertical aligned to center content displayed as table-cell

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Peace in the world</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Personally I actually disagree about use helpers for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Try this solution with pure CSS http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/4RPFa/72/

Maybe it is the main problem with your HTML. You're not using quotes when you define c`lass` & `image height` in your HTML.

CSS:

```
.frame {
    height: 25px;      /* Equals maximum image height */
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em 0;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 25px;
}
```

When I work around with the `img` tag it's leaving 3 pixels to 2 pixels space from `top`. Now I decrease `line-height`, and it's working.

CSS:

```
    .frame {
        height: 25px;      /* Equals maximum image height */
        width: 160px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin: 1em 0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 22px;
        *:first-child+html line-height:24px; /* For Internet Explorer 7 */
    }

    img {
        background: #3A6F9A;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 0;    
        max-height: 25px;
        max-width: 160px;
    }
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .frame {
        line-height:20px; /* WebKit browsers */
    }
```

The `line-height` property is rendered differently in different browsers. So, we have to define different `line-height` property browsers.

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/4be8t/11/

Check this example about `line-height` different in different browsers: *[input height differences in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229568/input-height-differences-in-firefox-and-chrome)*

Comment: Doesn't work (at least in Firefox). For the missing quotes, this is allowed in HTML5 (don't know which doctype is used in jsfiddle though)

Answer (score 7):

My solution: http://jsfiddle.net/XNAj6/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="frame">
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" class="img" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.frame {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-width: 0;
}
.img {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure about Internet Explorer, but under Firefox and Chrome, if you have an `img` in a `div` container, the following CSS content should work. At least for me it works well:

```
div.img-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 450px;
    width: 490px;
}

div.img-container img {
    max-height: 450px;
    max-width: 490px;
}
```

Comment: IE8+, unfortunately. Fine for me, but maybe not for others.

Comment: also note that `display:table-cell;` doesn't accept % as widths

Answer (score 6):

An easy way which work for me:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

It works for Google Chrome very well. Try this one out in a different browser.

Answer (score 6):

For centering an image inside a container (it could be a logo) besides some text like this:

[image]

Basically you wrap the image

```css
.outer-frame {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center; /* Only to align horizontally */
}

.wrapper{
  line-height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 50px
}

img {
  /* height: auto; */
  vertical-align: middle;   /* Only to align vertically */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-frame">
  <div class="wrapper">
    some text
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can live with pixel-sized margins, just add `font-size: 1px;` to the `.frame`. But remember, that now on the `.frame` 1em = 1px, which means, you need to set the margin in pixels too.

http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/4RPFa/96/

Now it's not centered any more in Opera…

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. This works for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.parent {
        position: relative;
    }

    img.child {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="parent">
    <img class="child">
</div>
```

Comment: actually the "position: fixed" on the image worked for me where i've been frustrated over the numerous false answers of people suggesting the table-cell method that didn't work in neighter of my works. With the method suggested by algreat you don't need an extra container too.

Answer (score 4):

I add a new solution to this old question because I see that my preferred method is not included in the answers.

In every project, at the very beginning, I create 2 CSS classes

```
.flex-centered {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction-column; 
    justify-content:center
}
.abs-centered {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

You can center elements with both, depending on the situation.

flex-centered is more versatile for images and content on the page,
abs-centered need a relative parent is good for centered div, like popups.

So you just call

```
   <div class='flex-centered'>
        <img>
    </div>
```

and the image is vertically centered.

```css
.flex-centered {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* this to center horizontally, too */
.m0a {
  margin: 0 auto
}

 /* Make a big parent grey */
.big-div { 
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
 
 /* Make a small div to be centered */
.small-div { 
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex-centered big-div" >
  <div class="small-div m0a"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
 .loaderimage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: -30px; /* 50% of the height */
    margin-left: -30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Want to align an image which have after a text / title and both are inside a div?

See on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariusfv/fwyxjznt/) or Run Code Snippet.

Just be sure to have an ID or a class at all your elements (div, img, title, etc.).

For me works this solution on all browsers (for mobile devices you must to adapt your code with: @media).

```css
h2.h2red {
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.mydivclass {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: block;
}
img.mydesiredclass {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left; /* If you want to allign the text with an image on the same row */
    width: 100px;
    heght: 100px;
    margin-top: -40px /* Change this value to adapt to your page */;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydivclass">
    <br />
    <img class="mydesiredclass" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg/2000px-Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg.png">
    <h2 class="h2red">Text aligned after image inside a div by negative manipulate the img position</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `table` and `table-cell` method do the job, specially because you targeting some old browsers as well, I create a snippet for you which you can run it and check the result:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.inside {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inside">
    <p>Centre me please!!!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inside">
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-icons-circular-black/512/stackoverflow-128.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of this being a valid answer I still want to post the jQuery solution again. This works for every element that has the `v_align` class applied to it. It will be vertical centered in the parent and on resizing of the window it will be recalculated.

[Link to the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ot95wkur/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Define the class that vertically aligns stuff
  var objects = '.v_align';
  // initial setup
  verticalAlign(objects);

  // Register resize event listener
  $(window).resize(function() {
    verticalAlign(objects);
  });
});

function verticalAlign(selector) {
  $(selector).each(function(val) {
    var parent_height = $(this).parent().height();
    var dif = parent_height - $(this).height()
    // Should only work if the parent is larger than the element
    var margin_top = dif > 0 ? dif/2 : 0;
    $(this).css("margin-top", margin_top + "px");
  });
}
```

Comment: Great! some times we depend on code instead of CSS!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is that

```
.block{
    /* Decor */
    padding:0 20px;
    background: #666;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    /* Important */
    min-height: 220px;
    width: 260px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.block:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 220px; /* The same as min-height */
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.block span{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with using padding for center alignment. You will need to define the top level outer-container size, but the inner container should resize, and you can set the padding at different percentage values.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/q8bq79c1/)

```
<div class='container'>
  <img src='image.jpg' />
</div>

.container {
  padding: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
position: absolute;
top: calc(50% - 0.5em);
left: calc(50% - 0.5em);
line-height: 1em;
```

And you can vary `font-size`.

Answer (score 0):

This code work well for me.

```
<style>
    .listing_container{width:300px; height:300px;font: 0/0 a;}
    .listing_container:before { content: ' ';display: inline-block;vertical-align: bottom;height: 100%;}
    .listing_container img{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;font: 16px/1 Arial sans-serif; max-height:100%; max-width:100%;}
<style>

<div class="listing_container">
    <img src="http://www.advancewebsites.com/img/theme1/logo.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use table structure inside a div

```
<div class="frame">
     <table width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td vertical-align="middle" align="center" height="25">
                <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" >  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Never use a table structure for images... Tables must only be used for displaying textual content and even then I would prefer a wel styled `div`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `grid` layout to vertically center the image.

```
.frame {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "."
                       "img"
                       "."
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}
.frame img {
  grid-area: img;
}
```

This will create a 3 row 1 column grid layout with unnamed 1 fraction wide spacers at the top and bottom, and an area named `img` of `auto` height (size of the content).

The `img` will use the space it prefers, and the spacers at top and bottom will use the remaining height split to two equal fractions, resulting in the `img` element to be vertically centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kissaki0/4RPFa/20713/

Answer (score -2):

I was looking for a similar answer and some of the suggestions snapped the image to the left or the vertical ratio squashed the image, so I came up with this solution... It centers the content vertically and horizontally.

```
 .div{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
 .bantop img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 103%;
    height: auto;
    top: -50%;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    right: -50%;
  }
```

I use it on several projects and it works like a charm.