# How to make both element inside a table has the same height

Tags: css, google-chrome

So I have made something like this in firefox browser :

[image]

But in chrome (v53). The height property is not equal :

[image]

There is a difference of 1px of height.
Is there any solution? If you want to see the live page, just visit [my site here](https://pastipandai.com)

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Update with what have you tried  ?

Comment: Post your markup and CSS, links to sites and external resources can disappear, and when they do this question will be useless

Comment: This problem is common
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229568/input-height-differences-in-firefox-and-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to remove the individual borders on each div and just use the container to get what you need,

https://jsfiddle.net/uqdmvonv/

Example:

```
div.pp-footer1-container1 div.pp-footer1-fill4{
    display: table;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
div.pp-footer1-container1 div.pp-footer1-fill4{
    border: none;
    border-right: 2px solid white; // This is for that middle bar
}
div.pp-footer1-container1 div.pp-footer1-fill4 a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: #ff0000;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
```