# Doesn't line-height work with height on text input in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, specifications

I played with text inputs and found an interesting thing — it seems like Firefox (40, OS X) doesn't react on changing `line-height` when `height` is set, unlike other browsers (for example, Chrome). Why?

**Chrome:**
[image: Chrome]

**Firefox:**
[image: Firefox]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/5o99cznL/3/)

```css
input {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="222222222222222222"/>
```

**P.S.** My question isn't a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650530/firefox-line-height-issue-with-input-fields). That question is about the old issue with `line-height: normal !important` in default Firefox styles, which is fixed now. In my case styles is applied well, but seems like don't work:
[image: Styles]

Comment: Well the question would be, what effect would you expect to happen when you change the spacing between lines of text on an element that can only ever have a single line of text?

Comment: @showdev it's not a duplicate, I've just explained it in the **P.S.** part of the question.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I tried to vertically align text in an input for all supported browsers. The example in my question is only for show that `line-height` isn't working in a case like this in Firefox.

Comment: Looks like it is vertically centered just fine in firefox.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov Fair enough. I did not see that behavior had been changed. However, I do see in the documentation for [line-height at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) that "[o]n replaced inline elements such as buttons or other input element, line-height has no effect." And also: "Neither Webkit nor Trident implement the correct behavior with replaced inline elements like buttons. In some cases line-height is allowed to have an effect on them. This is incorrect behavior relative to the specification."

Comment: @showdev it's really interesting, thanks, I read some information about *replaced/non-replaced* elements. But now I don't understand why in reality in Firefox on *replaced* inline elements such as `<button>` or `<input type="button"/>` `line-height` **has** effect? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/p4wa79ga/1/).

Comment: @RobertMcKee in this case yes, but in my real case — not always.

Comment: The problem is that form elements, which used to be implemented as true replaced elements (i.e. rendering was delegated to O/S widgets), aren't really replaced elements any more. But they, in many ways, need to behave in a backward compatible fashion, so inhabit a twilight world or not completely replaced, not completely non-replaced elements. As a result, different browsers draw the line in different places. Chrome has a long history of being of favouring the non-replaced side, Firefox favouring the replaced side, and this seems borne out again in this instance.

Comment: @Alohci thanks for explanation! Could you post it as an answer? Please, add some articles about concrete realizations in Chrome/Firefox/IE. I'd appreciate and accept it.