# WebKit renders text in input higher than in div

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, webkit

I'm attempting to normalize an `input` field to display as a `div`, giving the elements the same height in both Firefox and WebKit. When I noticed that WebKit will render a `16px/16px` text `18px` high, while Firefox will correctly render it `16px`.

What is causing this height difference and how do I remove it?

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("div").offsetHeight)
console.log(document.querySelector("input").offsetHeight)
```

```css
div,
input {
  font: 16px/16px Arial;
}

input {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<input type="text" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a problem about how line-height renders different on inputs between Firefox and Chrome.

Just resetting the line-height will resolve the issue:

```
line-height: normal;
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("div").offsetHeight)
console.log(document.querySelector("input").offsetHeight)
```

```css
div,
input {
  font: 16px Arial;
  line-height: normal;
}

input,div {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<input type="text" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
```

To explain a little more about the way that Chrome shows the input I've got to say it is related to "Chrome has a minimum for line-height on inputs".

For example, if you set line-height to 17px and font size to 16px there won't be any issues.

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185205/text-input-on-chrome-line-height-seems-to-have-a-minimum)

Comment: You've missed this construct: `font: 16px/16px` in original message. It translates to  `font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px` thus TS already set line-height to desired value.

Comment: yep. changed the answer. but it remains the problem with how WebKit renders line height on inputs