# default line-height setting truncates Segoe UI

Tags: css, google-chrome, normalize-css, line-height

Chrome is truncating the display of Segoe UI when used with a `line-height` of 1.15 (default setting of [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)) This behaviour does not occur on Firefox

This is best illustrated via a screenshot (zoomed in instead of using larger fonts)

[image]

You can see a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vooose/kfnaL4ev/10/)

Why is Chrome truncating the g character?  Why would the problem get *worse* as you decrease the line height then moving in the same direction get better?

*Please note adding `padding` to the input does not address the issue*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text input on Chrome: line-height seems to have a minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185205/text-input-on-chrome-line-height-seems-to-have-a-minimum)

Comment: @gekkedev could you explain how it is a duplicate? there is no mention of truncating text

Comment: After some experimenting, it appears to me that Chrome has a minimal line-height which creates the relation in my eyes. When you use values like 0.5, it will even get bigger again. That question has some deeply explanatory answers with some workarounds.

Comment: FF 60.0.2 / Chrome 77.0.3865.90 Same issue, `Segoe UI` requires  `25px` height wise to account for every descender `p,g,y` etc..., basically `line-height:1.5` to be safe